# Getting 'Future<Image>' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'Image' in this Flutter/Dart code?

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-async

I'm trying create a function to load images in Flutter (Dart) but not sure how to get this code working.  I'm getting:

*A value of type 'Future' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'Image'.
Try changing the type of the variable, or casting the right-hand type to 'Image'.*

```
import 'dart:typed_data';
import 'dart:ui' as ui;
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  ui.Image _backgroundImage;

  Future<ui.Image> loadImage(imageString) async {
    ByteData bd = await rootBundle.load(imageString);
    // ByteData bd = await rootBundle.load("graphics/bar-1920×1080.jpg");
    final Uint8List bytes = Uint8List.view(bd.buffer);
    final ui.Codec codec = await ui.instantiateImageCodec(bytes);
    final ui.Image image = (await codec.getNextFrame()).image;
    return image;
    // setState(() => imageStateVarible = image);
  }  

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    setState( () => {
      _backgroundImage = loadImage('imageNameString');  // <<== ISSUE: A value of type 'Future<Image>' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'Image'
    });

    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Text('testing'),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. Your problem is:

1. should not call things like "download an image" inside build. That should be a pure function.
2. Your loadImage is async. Thus I call it inside the _asyncInit. In addition, you may only want to load the image *once* (instead of every build), so I put in initState.

```
import 'dart:typed_data';
import 'dart:ui' as ui;

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  ui.Image _backgroundImage;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _asyncInit();
  }

  Future<void> _asyncInit() async {
    final image = await loadImage('imageNameString');
    setState(() {
      _backgroundImage = image;
    });
  }

  Future<ui.Image> loadImage(imageString) async {
    ByteData bd = await rootBundle.load(imageString);
    // ByteData bd = await rootBundle.load("graphics/bar-1920×1080.jpg");
    final Uint8List bytes = Uint8List.view(bd.buffer);
    final ui.Codec codec = await ui.instantiateImageCodec(bytes);
    final ui.Image image = (await codec.getNextFrame()).image;
    return image;
    // setState(() => imageStateVarible = image);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: _backgroundImage != null ? YourWidget(_backgroundImage) : Text('you are loading that image'),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**EDIT**:

If you want an array of images:

```
import 'dart:typed_data';
import 'dart:ui' as ui;

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  List<ui.Image> _backgroundImages;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _asyncInit();
  }

  Future<void> _asyncInit() async {
    final imageNames = ['firstimage', 'secondimage', 'thirdimage'];
    // NOTE by doing this, your images are loaded **simutanously** instead of **waiting for one to finish before starting the next**
    final futures = [for (final name in imageNames) loadImage(name)];
    final images = await Future.wait(futures);
    setState(() {
      _backgroundImages = images;
    });
  }

  Future<ui.Image> loadImage(imageString) async {
    ByteData bd = await rootBundle.load(imageString);
    // ByteData bd = await rootBundle.load("graphics/bar-1920×1080.jpg");
    final Uint8List bytes = Uint8List.view(bd.buffer);
    final ui.Codec codec = await ui.instantiateImageCodec(bytes);
    final ui.Image image = (await codec.getNextFrame()).image;
    return image;
    // setState(() => imageStateVarible = image);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: _backgroundImages != null ? YourWidget(_backgroundImages) : Text('you are loading that image'),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks - that fixes issue - actually if I ultimately wanted to loop through an array of images to preload, what would the _asyncInit() function need to look like? (or should I raise separate question?)

Comment: great stuff thank you - hopefully this async stuff will click soon.  :)

Comment: do you happen to know if you have an array of something as state, when you update the array does that trigger update (redraw) on all items in the array, or just the ones that have changed?

Comment: @Greg No, *nothing* will happen automatically. Actually, the magic happens in `setState` - setState means "mark this statefulwidget as needing to rebuild". You may create another question, such that other people having this question can also benefit, and I can elaborate a bit, for example, digging into source code :)

Comment: by the way - just created new question:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65838077/array-of-items-as-state-in-a-statefulwidget-ensuring-setstate-only-triggers

Comment: @Greg Let me have a look